# meteor stuck on "scanning local packages"

Tags: meteor

Since the upgrade to 1.4 Ive been having tonnes of issues. This is the latest, it builds, I can run the project, but if I make any changes it stays stuck here. I have to restart it to make it run. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?